# Run ant script on remote which is present locally

Tags: ant, ssh, remote-access

I used ant sshsession task in my ant script but the commands inside sequential is running on local machine only as it trying to access path of local machine. I want after connection is set up it should read and write the path of remote machine.

```
 Script I am using:
    <sshsession host="demo"
    username="admin"
    password="Test"
   trust="true">
     <sequential>
   <property name="worklight" value="/Users/MobileFirst_Platform_Server"/>
 </sequential>
 </sshsession>
```

It is searching property value locally but I think it should search on remote system .I don't know why this happening.
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to browse to a directory on a remote server by using SSHSession command.

The way I run a command on my remote Workligh server is by using the following script:

**Edite:**

Added the script on remote server to be executed:

```
<property name="SERVER_IP" value="A.B.C.D" />
<property name="SERVER_USERNAME" value="*******" />
<property name="SERVER_PASSWORD" value="*******" />

<target name = "host">
        <sshexec host="${SERVER_IP}"
        username="${SERVER_USERNAME}"
        password="${SERVER_PASSWORD}"
        trust="true"
        Command="(cd "PUT THE DIRECTORY OF THE SERVER THAT YOU NEED"; script.xml "target-name")"/>
</target>
```

Comment: thanks @Husaam Eddin but I want to run a whole ant script not only a command because I don't want to keep my script at remote machine for this I found sshsession will work for my requirement but it is not. Hussam can u help me with this

Comment: Ok, you need to use the script above to 1- connect to remote server, 2- browse to the directory existed on the server, 3- run another script on the server directory. correct?

Comment: I need to know what you are trying to accomplish after you are in the server directory, your question or your request is not clear to me. Let me know so I can modify my answer to meet your needs.

Comment: I am trying to run a ant script existing at local server but it run on remote server accessing it's all directories. I don't want to send or copy my ant script at remote.

Comment: I don't think you can run an ant script on your local server to be executed on the remote server without copying the script to the remote server. What I do is I use an ant script on my local machine to connect to the remote server and execute a different script on the server directory.

Comment: so what does sshsession exactly does..it just connect to remote server and inside it commands are run on local machine. So what exactly is the use of sshsession I am bit confused